# Isolate one specific instance of a word in a string

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a `grep` command to process the string

```
test-test test
```

I want the command to only show me the "free-standing" word `test` highlighted, but not `test-test`.

However, when I run

```shell
echo "test-test test" | grep -w "test"
```

I get all `test` occurences highlighted.

Is it possible to restrict the matching to only the isolated occurence of `test`?

Comment: What is your expected/desired output if the input is "For a contest I took a test, but people were protesting during my test and I tested badly." with two instances of standalone "test" (the first of which is followed by punctuation) and three instances of "test" that are embedded within a longer word (one at the beginning, one at the end, and one in the middle)?

Comment: Shouldn't your test code include the `-o` (i.e. `--only-matching`) option? As in: `~$ echo "test-test test" | grep -w -o "test"` (code returns three matches on `test`, one per line). Otherwise, how are you visualizing your return (e.g. `--color`)? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get all `test` occurrences in bold because for `-w` a word is a sequence of word characters delimited by non-word characters, word characters being alphanumerics and underscores. `-` is not a word character.

In `testing-test+test2;test_3;untested`, only the second `test` occurrence matches because that's the only one that is neither preceded nor followed by a word character.

If you want to match on whitespace-delimited words, you'll have to specify those *look-around* assertions by hand, and you'll need perl-compatible regexps for that which not all `grep` implementations support. Since you seem to have a `grep='grep --color` alias, if your `grep` supports `--color`, there's a chance it also supports a `-P` / `-X perl` option, and then you can do:

```
grep --color -P '(?<!\S)test(?!\S)'
```

`(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` being respectively the [negative look-behind and look-ahead assertion operators in perl regexps](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions). `\S`, like POSIX' `[^[:space:]]` matches and character that is not classified as whitespace. So that says: "match on `test` provided it's neither preceded nor followed by a non-whitespace character".

Answer (score 2):

With Perl regexes (supported in GNU grep with the `-P` flag), you can use a negative lookbehind and lookahead to assert that the match for `test` is not adjacent to a `-`:

```
echo "test-test test" | grep -P '(?<!-)test(?!-)'
```

This outputs

```
test-test test
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can share link to official manual/doc. I want to read about and can not find it. Only stackexchange and forums.

Comment: For more documentation, try `man grep` or possibly search online for many regex tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Perl**:

```bash
~$ echo "test-test test\ntest\n\n" | perl -lpe 's/(?<!\S)(test)(?!\S)/**$1**/g;'
test-test **test**
**test**
```

Using **Raku**:

```bash
~$ echo "test-test test\ntest\n\n" | raku -pe 's:g/ <!after \S > (test) <!before \S >  /**$0**/;'
test-test **test**
**test**
```

[Special thanks to @StéphaneChazelas for expostulating on Perl-style Lookarounds in his `grep` answer].

If you want something akin to highlighting here's a simple idea from [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=106191). Instead of `grep`'s color option, use Perl/Raku and surround the matches with `**` asterisks.

Raku note: Lookbehinds are spelled `after` in Raku with `?` for positive and `!` for negative, while Lookaheads are spelled `before` in Raku with `?` for positive and `!` for negative. So you can literally read the Raku code above as *"substitute globally any matches to the word "test" not `after` a non-whitespace character and also not `before` a non-whitespace character... ".*

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Lookahead_assertions
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Lookbehind_assertions

Answer (score 0):

Using extended regex, you can achieve it like so

```
grep -E "(^| )test( |$)"
```

With the minor caveat that this will actually highlight any leading or training space, but you won't see it because it's not a printable character.